# Plotting the derivatives of an interpolation function of two variables

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to show how g1 and g2 changes with s1 below and want a surface plot but it the parametric3Dplot doesn't show me the result!

```
Clear[d1, d2, d3, d4, L, Δs, s1, s2, sp, sm, H, HT, IM, \
v, smin, smax, f, g1, g2]
d1 = 1; d2 = 2; d3 = 4; d4 = 3;
smin = -1; smax = 1; Δs = 0.1;
L = 5;
sp = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
sm = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
n = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}};
v = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
IM = IdentityMatrix[2];
H = 
  MatrixForm[
    {{0, E^-s1 d1, E^s1 d3, 0}, {0, -d1 - d2 - s2/2, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, -d3 - d4 - s2/2, 0}, {0, E^-s1 d2, E^s1 d4, -s2}}];
HT = KroneckerProduct[H, IM, IM, IM] +
   KroneckerProduct[IM, H, IM, IM] +
   KroneckerProduct[IM, IM, H, IM] +
   KroneckerProduct[IM, IM, IM, H] +
   (d1*E^-s1) KroneckerProduct[sp, IM, IM, IM, 
     v] + (d3*E^s1) KroneckerProduct[v, IM, IM, IM, 
     sp] + (d2*E^-s1) KroneckerProduct[n, IM, IM, IM, 
     sm] + (d4*E^s1) KroneckerProduct[sm, IM, IM, IM, 
 n] - (d1) KroneckerProduct[n, IM, IM, IM, 
 v] - (d3) KroneckerProduct[v, IM, IM, IM, 
 n] - (d2) KroneckerProduct[n, IM, IM, IM, 
 v] - (d4) KroneckerProduct[v, IM, IM, IM, n] - (s2/
 2) KroneckerProduct[n, IM, IM, IM, v] - (s2/2) KroneckerProduct[
 v, IM, IM, IM, n] - (s2) KroneckerProduct[n, IM, IM, IM, n];

Table[Max[Re[Eigenvalues[HT]]], {s1,smin,smax,Δs}, 
{s2,smin,smax,Δs}];
 f = ListInterpolation[%, {{smin, smax}, {smin, smax}}];
g1[s1_] = -D[f[s1, s2], {s1, 1}] /. s2 -> 0;
g2[s1_] = -D[f[s1, s2], {s2, 1}] /. s2 -> 0;
 ParametricPlot3D[{g1[s1], g2[s1]}, {s1, smin, smax}]
```

Comment: 1. Get rid of the `MatrixForm` - it's meant for display purposes and should not be a part of your calculation. 2. Use `ParametricPlot` not `ParametricPlot3D`

Comment: @SimonWoods Now I know why it was taking time to run this code. Thx

Comment: thanx for the MatrixForm point. but again it doesn't show the result. It's just the axes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think it is easier to get results with `Derivative` rather than `D`.

```
Clear[g1, g2]
g1 = Derivative[1][-f[#1, #2] &]
```

> `-Derivative[1, 0][f][#1, #2]&`

```
g2 = Derivative[0, 1][-f[#1, #2] &]
```

> `-Derivative[0, 1][f][#1, #2]&`

```
Plot3D[{g1[s1, 0], g2[s1, 0]}, {s1, smin, smax}, {s2, smin, smax},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

This is an attempt to answer an issue raise by the OP in a comment.

I don't think what you are asking for in your comment is meaningful. At least, I can't understand what you are getting at. There really isn't a 2nd axis to plot `g2[s1, 0]` on.

Here is a way I think you might better visualize the two derivative slices.

```
Plot[{g1[s1, 0], g2[s1, 0]}, {s1, smin, smax}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: 2Dplot]

On the other hand, perhaps you really want this:

```
Plot3D[{g1[s1, s2], g2[s1, s2]}, {s1, smin, smax}, {s2, smin, smax}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image: 3Dplot]
[image: 3Dplot]

I admit I am really confused about what you are trying to visualize.

Comment: How I will know, when to use `D` and `Derivative`?

Comment: @MMM. I would recommend reading the docs for both functions thoroughly and carefully. My personal heuristic is `D` for expressions and `Derivative` for functions. With `D` it is easier to get tangled up in variable scoping.

Comment: @m_goldberg thats alright but do you know how I can plot one of these surfaces in which one of the axes is g1 the other one is g2 and another is s1?!

Comment: @m_goldberg OP is asking for something like this `ParametricPlot[{g1[s1, 0], g2[s1, 0]}, {s1, smin, smax}]`.

Comment: @MMM. Haven't you already provided that?

Comment: @m_goldberg I did but OP wants a surface like thing, I guess.

Comment: @MMM. But I can't imagine what surface that could be. I'm trying to get the OP to clarify her thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is taking too much time to run. So without running it, I suggest that, since `g1[s1]` and `g2[s1]` are only functions of `s1`, so you should use, `ParametricPlot`.

If `s2` is not fixed then for `g1[s1, s2]` and `g2[s1, s2]`, you can use `ParametricPlot3D`. For more details see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html).

Alternatively you can do this

```
ParametricPlot3D[{g1[s1], g2[s1], s1}, {s1, smin, smax}]
```

**Edit**

Thanks to @SimonWoods, once `MatrixForm` is removed the code runs as it should be.

```
ParametricPlot[{g1[s1], g2[s1]}, {s1, smin, smax}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{g1[s1], g2[s1], s1}, {s1, smin, smax}]
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't either shoe the result for ParametricPlot3D and ParametricPlot. don't know why?

Comment: @sarakaviani Quit your kernel and then run the code.  From menu bar click `Evaluation` then `Quit Kernel` and then click  on `Local`.

Comment: thanx I fixed it. but the problem with 3D is that it doesn't give me a surface. I need a surface